# WP replace shortcode in custom meta box

Tags: php, wordpress, formbuilder, meta-boxes

I am trying to figure out how to replace FormBuilder's shortcode [formbuilder:#] in a custom Meta Box.  Here is how I am getting the meta data:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
foreach($meta as $key => $value){
    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
}
```

I tried doing the_content() with no luck.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Or if anyone knows of any tutorials out there.

Here is the website for the formbuilder plugin:
[formbuilder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/formbuilder/)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this tip ;**

```
$t = get_post_meta($post->ID, "CUSTUM_META_KEY", true);
$trep = str_replace('[formbuilder:#]', '' , $t);
echo $trep;
```